# method isset does not work in php Site With AJAX

Tags: php, ajax

here is my header.php page that has links o some pages im using ajax to develop my site

```
<li><a href="log.php" class="ajaxtrigger">login</a></li>
<li><a href="chenge_pass.php" class="ajaxtrigger" >chenge password </a></li>
//some codes
<div id="target">  </div>
```

and here is my ajax code

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
  $('.ajaxtrigger').click(function(){
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#target').load(url);
    return false;
  });
});
```

any link with the class ajaxtrigger will load content via AJAX and display it in the element with the ID target. 
my problem is when i want for example change my pass word and click on link "change password" the page will called but text boxes not set (i think! because if(isset($_REQUEST["txt2"])) dose not return true!) and all codes in the 'if' dose not run 
here is my chenge_pass.php:

```
<form name="c" action="" method="POST">
last password<input class=fild name="txt2" type="password">
new password<input class=fild name="txt4" type="password" >
repeat new password<input class=fild name="txt3" type="password" >
<input class="btn b2" name="btn" type="submit" value="run">
 </form>
 <?php
   if(isset($_REQUEST["txt2"]))
  {
   if(!empty($_REQUEST["txt3"]) and !empty($_REQUEST["txt4"]) and !empty($_REQUEST["txt2"])  )
   {
    $txt3=($_REQUEST["txt3"]);
    $txt4= ($_REQUEST["txt4"]);
    $txt2=($_REQUEST["txt2"]);
    //code for save changes into mysql database
    }
    }
 ?>
```

what can i do to set my text boxes so i can save changes to my database??

Comment: Why should `$_REQUEST["txt2"]` be filled ? You have no params in your ajax call

Comment: i'm new in ajax ! i dont know how can i change the code for my goal!!

Comment: Okay, but that's not an ajax problem. Let's say your first page with the links is `index.html`. You load your form in it, and the form action is empty. So, sending the form will send the POST data to `index.html` because it's where your form is now. `chenge_pass.php` will not receive anything.

Comment: do i have change action=" " to action="index.php"??

Comment: Not really, you should rethink your code's architecture. I'll post an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is a bit vague... but if I may attempt to understand and summarize, it would be thus: "You have a page which loads the *chenge_pass.php* file via AJAX. Then on submission, you would want to do some *presence* validation on the fields before saving it to the database."

If this is true...

Your text fields will not be fixed because the contents in `#target` comes from a PHP file *chenge_pass.php* which is not currently visible to the browser's history (unless you're using push-state, which isn't indicated here).

So when submit the form (whose action from your specs default to the page pointed to by the browser's URL), the page would reload ...and you would have to re-trigger the click to see the password form, dare I say.

Now we are understood, there are two solutions to this

1. **Drop AJAX altogether**: This way, you can properly load the *chenge_pass.php* file as its own page. When the form submits, you can view the fields properly.
2. **Submit your password form via AJAX**: This is my go-to solution since the form is loaded via AJAX anyway.

Regardless of the option you choose, to fix what you said...

> the page will called but text boxes not set

...you would have to have something like this

```
<input class=fild name="txt2" type="password" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['txt2']?>">
```

This way, if you have $_REQUEST['txt2'] populated, it would show up in the form.

Answer (score 0):

when you click the link the form doesn't post, you must click the button `<input class="btn b2" name="btn" type="submit" value="run">` to post your form inputs.

and if you want process the ajax you should remove your href firstly:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="ajaxtrigger" >chenge password </a>
```

then you can post data by this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.ajaxtrigger').click(function(){
    var url = "chenge_pass.php";

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: url,
      data: $("form").serialize()
    });
 });
});
```

Comment: if you see my code up i have a button for this but don't work

Comment: i did change my href but it dose not show my form in change_pass.php any more

Answer (score 0):

Edit your form:
`<form name="c" action="chenge_pass.php" method="POST">`

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit unclear what you are asking, but from what I can see, you will be posting your forms to the wrong script.

When you load your form using ajax, you load this form:

```
<form name="c" action="" method="POST">
```

An empty `action` attribute will cause the form to post to the current page / script. And that is the page containing your links, not the `chenge_pass.php` script.

So to begin, you need to change that:

```
<form name="c" action="chenge_pass.php" method="POST">
```

Answer (score 0):

I find out that your href link is active ,**so it was run first before ajax run** so there is empty in your $_REQUEST["txt2"] is null .Try by insert onclick return false

```
<li><a href="chenge_pass.php" class="ajaxtrigger" onclick="return false;">chenge password </a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should rethink your code's architecture. If you are using ajax, try to separate your views and your php process, with something like that :

`application
    |
    |- controllers 
    |    |
    |    - change_passoword.php
    |
    |- views
    |    |
    |    - change_password.html
    |
    |- index.html`

> index.html

```
<html>
    <!-- Your html... -->
    <li><a href="log.php" class="ajaxtrigger">login</a></li>
    <li><a href="chenge_pass.php" class="ajaxtrigger" >chenge password </a></li>
    //some codes
    <div id="target">  </div>  
</html>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.ajaxtrigger').click(function(){
      var url = $(this).attr('href');
      $('#target').load(url);
      e.preventDefault();
  });
});
</script>
```

> views/change_password.html

```
<form id="myForm" name="c" action="controllers/change_password" method="POST">
    last password<input class=fild name="txt2" type="password">
    new password<input class=fild name="txt4" type="password" >
    repeat new password<input class=fild name="txt3" type="password" >
    <input class="btn b2" name="btn" type="submit" value="run">
</form>
<script>
    var form = $('#myForm');
    form.submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: form.attr('action'),
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "JSON",
            data: $('#myForm').serialize(),
            success: function(data) {
                // Do something
                // data is an object, data.success is a boolean, data.message is the controller message, see controllers/change_passwords.php to understand why
            },
            error: function(a,b,c) {
                console.error("Error during request", b);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

> controllers/change_password.php

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: application/json");
if (!empty($_POST) && !empty($_POST['txt2']) && !empty($_POST['txt3']) && !empty($_POST['txt4'])) {
    // Do your stuff here
    if ($allIsFine) { //If everything is fine
        echo json_encode(array("success" => true, "message" => "Your password has been changed"));
    } else {
        echo json_encode(array("success" => false, "message" => "Something went wrong"));
    }
} else {
    echo json_encode(array("success" => false, "message" => "Please fill and inputs"));
}
```